# Passing string options to custom style file, made simple?

Tags: macros

I would like to understand if there is a simple way to implement the following feature in LaTeX:

I would like to create mycustomsty.sty that I would call like this:

```
\usepackage[author={string1, string2, ..., stringN}]{mycustomsty}
```

and that would have the same output as simply typing:

```
\author{string1 \and string2 \and ... \and stringN}
```

directly in the TeX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The package `filecontents` is used to have one single file ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Of course you can put the sty in a separate file.
- Use [`kvoptions`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions) to pass the string to the package.
- Use [`xstring`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) to make string substitutions.
- To make it possible to replace a string with a command (`\and`), witch should not be expanded, but also interpret the inputstring as an expanded command `\expandarg` is used. (from [`xstring` documentation](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf): *"In this case, the first token of each argument is expanded one time while all other tokens are left unchanged"*)

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myauthorgenerator.sty}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
    \ProvidesClass{myauthorgenerator}[2018/06/03]

    \RequirePackage{kvoptions}
    \RequirePackage{xstring}

    \DeclareStringOption{author}[unknown]
    \ProcessKeyvalOptions*

    \author{%
        \saveexpandmode\expandarg%
        \StrSubstitute{\myauthorgenerator@author}{,}{\and }%
        \restoreexpandmode%
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[author={Frodo,Sam,Pippin, Merry}]{myauthorgenerator}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]